# Why am I getting the value error for DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, time-series

Getting an error while decomposing in time series.

This is my time series look like...2 years data with some zero values..

[image]

This is an error.
[image]

Please help !

help me removing the error so that I can proceed further

Comment: please replace the error message picture with its text equivalent.

Comment: It seems like Date is not actually a DatetimeIndex type - you can either make it that, or you can add `period=1` to the arguments to the decompose function

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems like the `Date` index column is not of `DatetimeIndex` type.

You could use:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    
    ts.index = pd.to_datetime(ts.index)
```

This is assuming `Date` is the index column. If not, then first use `ts.set_index()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.Series.asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html#pandas-series-asfreq):

```
ts = ts.asfreq('d')
```

to add a frequency to your DateTimeIndex of this pd.Series